# Consequences of dropping iOS 7 support for a live iOS app

Tags: ios

I have a couple of questions about an app that is currently compatible for iOS7 and above that I am looking to cut iOS 7 support for. I would like to know:

- What happens to our users that already have the app installed on their iOS 7 device? Will they just not be able to update the app or will it update and stop working for them? If so will they see an annoying red notification number above the App Store icon that they will not be able to get rid of?
- For new users what message will an iOS 7 user get when they try and download our app? Or will they just not see the app on the app store when they search for it?

Is the community cutting iOS 7 support yet? Apple says only 8% of App Store users have an operating system earlier than iOS 8 (https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/) but I would like to know the general communities current thoughts on this.

Comment: they will still be able to download an older version of the app, which supports iOS7, but they will not get any update anymore, until they update the iOS on their device; or if you'd like it: let us say your latest version is e.g. _1.1_ with iOS7 support, and the version _1.2_ supports iOS8+ only, then the existing users still can use or download version _1.1_ on their iOS7 devices, but they can't see or download version _1.2_ until they update iOS8+.

Comment: Note you will be dropping iphone 4 and ipad 1 devices which don't support iOS 8.

Comment: iPad 1 devices don't even support iOS 6; they will already have been lost.

Comment: @holex that seems weird to me that iOS 7 users will be able to see and download an older version of the app. Surely this is not the case?

Comment: @jakedunc, that is exactly how that works, if any previous version of your app has been submitted with e.g. iOS7 support; your app will not be invisible or removed from their end-users' devices just because you have dropped supporting e.g. iOS7 recently.

Answer (score 2):

Installed apps will still run, but not update.

As XCode 7 doesn't support iOS 7 simulators anymore, really testing for iOS 7 is getting increasingly difficult - and releasing a version that does not work correct for iOS 7 is worse than just letting people use their (still working) old version.

I would look at your own user base, some apps tend to have users with more older iOS versions than others. My apps have < 5% iOS 7, so I'll be dropping iOS 7 from now on.